# Creating typed array in TypeScript 0.9.0.1

Tags: typescript

How to create a typed array in `TypeScript 0.9.0.1`? In `0.8.x.x`, I created a typed array like this:

```
public myArray: myClass[] = new myClass[];
```

But in `TypeScript 0.9.0.1`, I get this error:

```
error TS2068: 'new T[]' cannot be used to create an array. Use 'new Array<T>() instead.
```

And if I try the following way:

```
public myArray: myClass[] = new myClass<myClass>();
```

I get another error. So, what's the correct way to create a typed array in TypeScript?

Answer (score 27):

Since TypeScript 0.9 you can use generics and do it like this:

```
var myArray = new Array<MyClass>();
```

Or like this (TS 0.9 and below):

```
var myArray: MyClass[] = [];
```

And this should also work (using cast operation):

```
var myArray = <MyClass[]>[];
```

I personally like the second and the first way.

Comment: how do you declare it as a field? like this? : **states:Array<State.State> = [];**

Comment: **states:Array<State.State> = new Array<State.State>;** doesn't work

Comment: @FutuToad Try `private a : T[] = []`.

Answer (score 6):

You do it like this... Only the type annotation needs the type:

```
var myArray: MyClass[] = [];
```

This tricks almost everyone at first - so your question is a good one.